# Accessing Images in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I'm a teacher attempting to use the AP Computer Science Picture Lab activity.  Here are the teacher instructions:

- Students should keep the images folder and the classes folder together in the pixLab folder.
- The FileChooser expects the images to be in a folder called images, at the same level as the classes folder.
- If it does not find the images there it also looks in the same folder as the class files that are executing.
- If you wish to modify this, change the `FileChooser.java` class to specify the folder where the pictures are stored. For example, if you want to store the images in `“r://student/images/,”` change the following line in the method `getMediaDirectory()` in `FileChooser.java`:

  ```
  URL fileURL = new URL(classURL,"../images/");
  ```

And modify it to
`URL fileURL = new URL("r://student/images/");`

I have created a GitHub repo for them to fork and use in Eclipse, but I'm having trouble getting the images in the right place for Eclipse to see them. Where should they be in the Eclipse Package Explorer?  The tree now is:

```
PixLab > src > default package > various classes.
```

At what level should I drag and drop the images folder into?

Alternatively, what should I the following line to read?

```
URL fileURL = new URL(classURL,"../images/");
```

Comment: What's "AP Computer Science Picture Lab activity"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if there is some confusion between the naming of the project in Eclipse with the folder name for the source files.

The directory structure that you give does not include a pixLab folder. I'd be expecting something more like the following in Eclipse:

```
PixLab > src > pixLab > various classes
             > images > various images
```

Then, the line:

```
URL fileURL = new URL(classURL,"../images/");
```

makes sense, as you are going up one level from the classes folder, and down from there to the images folder.

For the reference to a "student" folder, I think they are considering the scenario where the images are stored in a shared network file folder. In that case, they would NOT be part of the Eclipse package, and the FileChooser Url would have to be modified to reflect your chosen network location for the images.

If you've already set up the project in Eclipse with the "default package", can I suggest doing the following:

From within Eclipse:

1) make a package, named pixLab

2) drag & drop files from the default package to the new package

Eclipse should automatically add the following line to the top of all the source files that you brought over:

```
package pixLab;
```

3) place the images folder under src, parallel to the pixLab package.

A "package" functions as a folder. If everything is in the same folder, then the rest of the code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the attempt, but I'm afraid Java still can't find the jpg images.  I'm afraid I'm not yet allowed to post images, but I took a screenshot, and the files are laid out exactly as suggested above.  Any other ideas, anyone?